# Problem with port forwarding for Splashtop iPad application

Tags: port-forwarding, home-networking

I'm trying to configure my home network to work with Splashtop Remote application from my IPad. I have a home network behind a standard router and a standard modem. My computer is connected to the network with wireless communication with a static ip address(relevant?)

I configured the port forwarding to forward the 3 ports range used by the application & I also disabled windows firewall just in case but the computer in still unreachable from the internet.

I tested my port with [this](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) tool and all of them are closed (strange, isn't it?) I got the same results for standard ports like 80, 110, 25.

Would really appreciate your help with this, a bit frustrated here...

p.s. I am working with windows 7 os

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is use the app from inside your network - taking the router/forwarding out of the picture.  Does that work?